# Why doesn't the ratio of inertial to viscous forces ($R_e$) depend on the object shape - frontal vs side area?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, approximations

### Why doesn't $R_e$ depend on frontal and side area? - Understanding Reynolds number in the context of varying object geometries.

I have not taken a fluid dynamics course, but have been reading up on the Reynold's number and the meaning of viscous forces.

## Background

The Reynolds number compares inertial forces to viscous forces. When it is particularly large or small, we can drop one of the two terms. The equation is $R_e = \frac{\rho v L}{\mu}$, but I'm not sure what to use for the characteristic length $L$ and I feel like it's missing parts?

Inertial forces come from the change in momentum per unit time of air molecules being slowed by the object. It's proportional to $ρAv^2$, the mass flow rate times velocity.
$ρ$ is air density, $A$ is surface area, $v$ is wind speed.

Viscous forces come from layers of air sliding over each other.  When you are talking about two plates sliding over each other, the total force = (plate area)(viscosity)(change in velocity per unit distance). In the context of wind over an object, I expect the plate area is replaced with the length $l$ of the object in the wind direction times the object perimeter $P$. The distance over which the velocity changes is less clear, I only guess it grows with some measure of the size of the object, maybe that characteristic length $L$ from the Reynold's number. The viscous force thus increases as $(Pl)(\mu)(v / L)$.

The ratio of inertial and viscous forces would thus be $\frac{ρAv^2}{Pl\mu v / L} = \frac{ρvL}{\mu} \cdot \frac{A}{P l}$, or $R_e \cdot \frac{frontal\ area}{side\ area}$

## Question

But the true Reynolds number does not include this area comparision term:

1. Does that mean that viscous forces actually increase with the frontal area (which would cancel out the numerator in the second term)? Why ever would that be?
2. Do inertial forces increase with the side area? Again, why?

## My Motivation:

I'm approximating the forces due to wind drag over a long cylinder (overhead electric line), as $F_D = $ (frontal area)(wind pressure) = (frontal area)($\frac12 ρ v^2$) and I want to understand the assumptions present in my model, and how valid the approximation is.

$v$ is wind speed, $ρ$ is air density. This approximates how the air molecules lose momentum upon interacting with the object, and increases with $v^2$ not $v$, so I believe it is only incorporating intertial forces.

I want to say that's a good approximation because of the high wind speeds, large areas, and low viscosity involved.